# PHP: Download an image via its url and prompt user to saveit

Tags: php, download

Whats the best what to enable a user to click a download button that then automatically gets a image file and then downloads it to their generic downloads folder or prompts them to save it?

i have tried the following but with no success:

```
  $file = $art[0]['location']; // this is the full url to image http://....image.jpg
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); 
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $file); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  $file_content = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

ect or am i going about this all wrong (probably)

thanks

Comment: So your server is downloading it from someone else's server, then you want to deliver it straight to the user's browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you echo the data:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=save_as_name.jpg');
```

Then

```
echo file_get_contents("http://...");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="exmaple.jpg"');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); // (or a MIME type like "image/jpeg")

echo $file_content;
```